# Does Kendo include disemboweling techniques?

Tags: technique, sword, sport, kendo, kenjutsu

I don't know as much about Kendo as I'd like, but I've studied Chinese saber and straight sword, both of which include disemboweling techniques.

In the case of wudang fencing, techniques which require penetration are not utilized (for obvious reasons;) but saber methods I know do not require penetration to exhibit, just continuous blade-to-body contact, because you can press the curved blade into the body with the off hand. However, you don't have a highly developed wushu saber sparring sport like [Kendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendo).

Thus I'm wondering if Kendo discards these techniques to focus on clean hits in the competition sport, or if they have a place in the sport and practice.

- Does [Kendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendo) include disemboweling techniques or are these strictly [kenjutsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenjutsu)?

Information on the practice and techniques in kenjutsu also welcome for historical perspective.  My understanding is that such techniques were utilized in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The straigt answer is : no, there are no disembowelling techniques in Kendo. Today's Kendo is detached from its original martial purpose (which is nodawady found partially in the Kenju-tsu practice). A reminescence from such a technique is the "Do" strike which is intended to cut you in half.

The modern Kendo is the fruit of the principles established in the foundation of The All Japan Kendo Federation (All Japan Kendo Federation or Zen Nippon Kendo Renmei) which was done in 1952 when the ban on martial arts (particularly Kendo) in Japan was lifted.

It was agreed then that Kendo si no longer to be considered as a martial art, but as educational discipline and it has continued to be practiced as such to this day. Therefore it is much more refined and limited as set of techniques, focusing on the "Do" (the Way) aspect. Nevertheless it requires a great concentration and observation capacities as well as intense physical training. Kendokas develop with time great abilities to launch lightining fast attacks on ther adversaries, using fondamental sabre cutting techniques.

Kendo gi-geiko (the combat sessions) are sometimes commented to be "unrealistic" by  practionners from other sabre disciplines but you can be 100% assured that a trained kendoka is the most dangerous opponent you can ever meet regarding sabre combat.

For more information you can have a look at : https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kendo